# Elasticsearch bulk index api via rest endpoint

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

Here is my request:

```
POST /_bulk
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test", "_type" : "type1", "_id" : "1" } }
{"firstname":"first_name1","lastname":"last_name1"},
{"firstname":"first_name2","lastname":"last_name2"},
{"firstname":"first_name3","lastname":"last_name3"}}
```

Here is the error:

> ```
> {    "error": "IllegalArgumentException[Malformed action/metadata line [3], expected START_OBJECT or END_OBJECT but found
> ```
>
> [VALUE_STRING]]",    "status": 500 }

Basically, each document is {"firstname": ___, "lastname": ____} I don't want to wrap them into a parent field. What am I fundamentally missing?

Comment: this is also a helpful, related link: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/bulk-indexing-document-without-providing-id-using-php-api/25521/5

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're simply missing an action line for the second and third documents, try like this:

```
POST /_bulk
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test", "_type" : "type1", "_id" : "1" } }
{"firstname":"first_name1","lastname":"last_name1"}
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test", "_type" : "type1", "_id" : "2" } }
{"firstname":"first_name2","lastname":"last_name2"}
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test", "_type" : "type1", "_id" : "3" } }
{"firstname":"first_name3","lastname":"last_name3"}
```

Comment: The [Don't Repeat Yourself](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/bulk.html#_don_8217_t_repeat_yourself) section suggests a way to avoid repeating ```_index``` and ```_type``` value all the time. However, please note that, *action* must be still specified for each document.

Comment: Of course, it's always better to specify the index and the type directly in the URL if possible. That was just to illustrate the _bulk action

Comment: yes. Earlier, I got a wrong impression when I read the document and thought that providing *action* at only the beginning of the file would serve the purpose well. I learnt that's not the case hard way.

Comment: Is there a way to upload a multiple json data in same index with auto id increment ? @samyak-bhuta

Comment: How to add a timeout in the above bulk request?

Answer (score 4):

As Samyak says in his comment, "don't repeat yourself". This syntax is tidier.

```json
post /test/_type/_bulk
{ "index": {}}
{"firstname":"first_name1","lastname":"last_name1"}
{ "index": { }}
{ "name": "Test2", "data": "This is my test data2" }
```