# Kibana: Cant import Shakespeare.json on Sense Web Plugin

Tags: windows, elasticsearch, kibana, sense

I am trying to import shakespeare.json as per elastic search tutorial.

[Environment]

1. Elastic Search 2.1
2. Sense -Extension for Chrome

[Background]

When I paste `curl -XPUT localhost:9200/_bulk --data-binary @shakespeare.json`
on the sense tab(the extensions opens a new tab with 2 windows)
It's converted to `PUT /_bulk` and the output is

```
{
   "error": {
      "root_cause": [
         {
            "type": "parse_exception",
            "reason": "Failed to derive xcontent"
         }
      ],
      "type": "parse_exception",
      "reason": "Failed to derive xcontent"
   },
   "status": 400
}
```

[My Findings]

1. I have downloaded shakespeare.json locally, but I think Sense is not
   able to locate the path where the file resides(May be, I have the file at incorrect location)
2. I also tried finding the current directory for Sense, but I am not sure where would I find the index.html for chrome-extension in windows for this plug-in.
3. Whatever documentation I found, is Linux specific.

Any inputs appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not do this in Sense, but simply from the command line

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/_bulk --data-binary @shakespeare.json
```

Make sure to point to the correct path of the `shakespeare.json` file if it is not located in the directory you're in.

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/_bulk --data-binary @/path/to/shakespeare.json
```

**UPDATE**

If you run on Windows and you don't have the cURL command present, you can download cURL at https://curl.haxx.se/download.html

Comment: No worries, glad to help!

Comment: why am I getting Exception: STATUS_STACK_OVERFLOW at rip=001801D72B6 when trying to curl -XPUT?

Comment: @user829174 your `shakespeare.json` file might be too big, you might need to split it in two or three (or more). Give it a try.

Comment: shakespear.json contains index object for wach data entry. Is index object mandatory ? I am trying to export my json file without index object and it is throwing same error.

Comment: @Harshit I suggest you create a new question for your specific problem since this one was about import, not export.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I mean import. I am trying to import json file which do not have index object.

Comment: Nevermind. I found my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32863112/elasticsearch-bulk-index-api-via-rest-endpoint Thanks @Val

Answer (score 0):

In Latest ElasticSearch 6, to populate the sharespeare_6.0.json, the following is the curl command

curl -H Content-Type:application/x-ndjson -XPUT localhost:9200/shakespeare/doc/_bulk --data-binary @shakespeare_6.0.json