# Elasticsearch - Bulk insert using Sense

Tags: json, elasticsearch, sense

I am trying to do a bulk insert using a Sense. 
I have a json file on my system but not sure how to point to it from sense.
Syntax I am using:

```
POST /shakespeare/_bulk  -d C:\Development\elasticsearch-2.1.1\elasticsearch-2.1.1\shakespeare.json
```

I see this syntax online:

```
POST /shakespeare/_bulk  -d @abc.json
```

Where are we supposed to place this file?

Comment: This answer should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34670624/kibana-cant-import-shakespeare-json-on-sense-web-plugin/34672449#34672449