# Elasticsearch - Bulk insert using Sense Web Plugin in Windows

Tags: windows, elasticsearch, kibana, sense, elasticsearch-bulk-api

I am trying to import the accounts.json data using _bulk api as per the elastic search tutorial( https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/getting-started.html ). I'm using google-chrome's **Sense** plugin for this task.

When i paste the url `curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/bank/account/_bulk?pretty' --data-binary @accounts.json` on **Sense**, its converted to `POST /bank/account/_bulk?pretty`.

The solution here : [Kibana: Cant import Shakespeare.json on Sense Web Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34670624/kibana-cant-import-shakespeare-json-on-sense-web-plugin/34672449), says, to use **CURL** command. But on windows, the curl command is not recognized.

`curl -XPUT localhost:9200/_bulk --data-binary @shakespeare.json
'curl' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Comment: You can download curl for Windows at https://curl.haxx.se/download.html

Comment: @Val This is also not working correctly, getting this error:                       `curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/bank/account/_bulk?pretty' --data-binary @accounts.json`                                                                                      
`curl: (6) Could not resolve host: 'localhost '`

Comment: OK, I got it, it worked with : `curl -XPOST localhost:9200/bank/account/_bulk?pretty --data-binary @accounts.json`. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: In which path you saved the accounts.jason file...
How to mention the path in Chrome Sense

Comment: The current version of sense does not support **--data-binary** option, so we cannot specify the data file. For this either use the **curl** command or perform a **_bulk** import.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
POST /<indexName>/<type>/_bulk
```

Copy the contents of the files accounts.json

and run.

Comment: This process is ok with small amount of data, but when the data is very large, the copy-paste doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Just to have the correct answer:

1. Download curl for Windows here: https://curl.haxx.se/download.html

   [Direct link to curl-7.54.1-win64-mingw](https://bintray.com/artifact/download/vszakats/generic/curl-7.54.1-win64-mingw.7z)
2. Unpack the `bin` folder from the archive somewhere on your local drive.
3. Add the path to that folder to your PATH system variable.
4. Restart your `explorer.exe` process or restart Windows. This is needed in order for the shell to refresh the value of PATH.
5. In the command-line shell, execute the following command:

   ```
   curl -XPOST localhost:9200/{some path here}/_bulk?pretty --data-binary @{file name}
   ```