# Do we can upload data into Elasticsearch using JSON file

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to *Elasticsearch*, I would like to know whether we can transfer data in to *Elasticsearch* using **JSON** file.

Please help me with the process if its there, I tried doing like below:

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/_bulk --databinary @shakespeare.json"
```

But I am getting an error "`could not connect to host`".

Comment: This answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34670624/kibana-cant-import-shakespeare-json-on-sense-web-plugin/34672449#34672449

Answer (score 0):

Try below curl command.

```
curl -s -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/<indexName>/<indexType>/_bulk?pretty" --data-binary "@shakespeare.json"
```