# Getting unknown setting [index._id] error while adding data to Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have created a mapping `eventlog` in Elasticsearch 5.1.1. I added it successfully however while adding data under it, I am getting `Illegal_argument_exception` with reason `unknown setting [index._id]`. My result from getting the indices is `yellow open eventlog sX9BYIcOQLSKoJQcbn1uxg 5 1 0 0 795b 795b`

My mapping is:

```
{
  "mappings" : {
    "_default_" : {
      "properties" : {
          "datetime" : {"type": "date"},
          "ip" : {"type": "ip"},
          "country" : { "type" : "keyword" },
          "state" : { "type" : "keyword" },
          "city" : { "type" : "keyword" }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

and I am adding the data using

```
curl -u elastic:changeme -XPUT 'http://localhost:8200/eventlog' -d '{"index":{"_id":1}}
{"datetime":"2016-03-31T12:10:11Z","ip":"100.40.135.29","country":"US","state":"NY","city":"Highland"}';
```

If I don't include the `{"index":{"_id":1}}` line, I get `Illegal_argument_exception` with reason `unknown setting [index.apiKey]`.

Comment: Try by removing '_' in id {"index":{"id":1}}

Comment: @vinod_vh Tried that. Didn't work. Now I'm getting `unknown setting [index.id]`.

Comment: Then better pass json file http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41261302/do-we-can-upload-data-into-elasticsearch-using-json-file/41262017#41262017

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was arising with sending the data from the command line as a string. Keeping the data in a `JSON` file and sending it as `binary` solved it. The correct command is:

```
curl -u elastic:changeme -XPUT 'http://localhost:8200/eventlog/_bulk?pretty' --data-binary @eventlogs.json
```