# How I can push data in elastic search through Rest Client

Tags: rest, elasticsearch

I want to push data in elastic search through rest client.

URL: localhost:9200/fcqa/type/_bulk

PUT: # my json data

I got parse error white pushing the data.

Comment: You need to show exactly what command you're running and what JSON data you're sending.

Comment: Here is my data: {"index":{"_index":"fcqa","_type":"search","_id":"1"}}
{"mydata":[{"firstname":"laren"},{"lastname":"matt"}]}

Comment: See this answer which might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32863112/elasticsearch-bulk-index-api-via-rest-endpoint

Comment: Cool, glad if it helped!