# How do I specify 2 or more documents to be indexed in the body of POST request in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to elasticsearch. I created an index by the name amenities and I am trying to execute a POST request in Postman tool, 
http://localhost:9200/amenities/test/_bulk.

Here, the content-type is set to application/json along with the error it gives upon executing the request.

[image]

Here, it shows a syntax error in the JSON.

[image]

I am unable to understand about how to index more than one JSON object (document). It works well when I have just one document specified but the JSON becomes invalid when I specify two or more.

I tried the following solutions:

{"index":{}}
{"type": "Kitchen","location": {"x": 9881.034723869176,"y": -12942.49413158995},"icon": "utensils","category": "Amenities"}
{"index":{}}
{"type": "Rubbish Bin","location": {"x": 9170.444649524274,"y": -12855.890257805067},"icon": "trash","category": "Amenities"}

{"index" : { "_index" : "amenities", "_type" : "test"}}
{"type": "Kitchen","location": {"x": 9881.034723869176,"y": -12942.49413158995},"icon": "utensils","category": "Amenities"}
{"index" : { "_index" : "amenities", "_type" : "test"}}
{"type": "Rubbish Bin","location": {"x": 9170.444649524274,"y": -12855.890257805067},"icon": "trash","category": "Amenities"}

which still gives a syntax error.

What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: This answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32863112/elasticsearch-bulk-index-api-via-rest-endpoint/32864366#32864366

Comment: @Val Thanks for your reply. I did try that solution as well and all it gives me is invalid JSON. It shows that there is a syntax error.

Comment: Can you update your question with what you tried? Also show your HTTP request headers.

Comment: @Val Sure thing!

Comment: The answer shared by @Val is correct but this syntax work with kibana console. the Postman body can not be adjacent objects like this.

Comment: @TarekEssam it is definitely possible to send that kind of queries with Postman, it doesn't only work in Kibana, but with any HTTP client, that's the whole point of using an HTTP interface in the first place.

Comment: @Val sure thing you can i meant the format of the body he was using in the postman was not going to work

Comment: @TarekEssam yes, but the same format he showed would not work with curl either, so it wasn't a question of curl vs Kibana. You implied that what he wrote only worked in Kibana, which is not correct. In the end, your answer is exactly the same as the one I linked to, basically a duplicate ;-)

Comment: This format work with curl using -d option and placing the body between single quotes. and it works with kibana like in the solution you shared But i don not know a way to make postman accepts this format. I will search again @Val

Comment: @TarekEssam see my answer below ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your docs in a json file in the following format (testData.json):

```
{"index": {"_index": "animals", "_type": "_doc", "_id": 1}}
{"name": "dog"}
{"index": {"_index": "animals", "_type": "_doc", "_id": 2}}
{"name": "cat"}
```

and use curl like this:

```
curl -s -H "Content-Type: application/x-ndjson" -XPOST localhost:9200/_bulk --data-binary "@testData.json";
```

OR if you want to use curl without a json file:

```
 curl -X POST "localhost:9200/_bulk" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test", "_type" : "_doc", "_id" : "1" } }
{ "field1" : "value1" }
{ "delete" : { "_index" : "test", "_type" : "_doc", "_id" : "2" } }
{ "create" : { "_index" : "test", "_type" : "_doc", "_id" : "3" } }
{ "field1" : "value3" }
{ "update" : {"_id" : "1", "_type" : "_doc", "_index" : "test"} }
{ "doc" : {"field2" : "value2"} }'
```

OR you can use kibana which is alot easier. check the docs [_bulk](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html)

Comment: Thanks! The request executed perfectly. I put my docs into a json file and provided it as a binary file in Postman and got a status of 200 OK. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the comments above, it is definitely possible to send a bulk query using Postman, it just needs to be formatted properly and sent in raw text as you can see below:

[image]

Also note that the Headers section contains a single HTTP header:

```
ContentType: application/x-ndjson
```

Comment: This also worked for me and I think it is the Content-Type which made the difference. I gave mine as application/json instead of application/x-ndjson. Thanks a ton! :)